# Kimono labs - extracting data from a page that scrolls

Tags: kimono

I am trying to extract data from a research platform,  the first x number of responses show on the page but when I try and scroll down the page to teach Kimono to extract the other responses it cant seem them thus just provides the first page.

Pagination doesn't work as the research platform is presenting a single page which is scrollable.

Anything I can do to teach Kimono to find the additional responses.

Answer (score 0):

They eliminated infinite scrolling capabilities mid 2015 so theres really no way.